# Negotiating with car insurance

Tags: united-states, car-insurance

Last month, someone ran their car into the back of my parked car. Therefore, this accident was 100% the other party's fault. Since it was not my fault, I did not file anything with my insurance company, other than a phone call immediately after the accident.

After having my car appraised for $1,300 by the other party's insurance company, I was wondering if I could ask for more? Since $1,300 only covers the repairs, should/can I ask for compensation for my troubles/time?

Both cars are insured in New York and the other party's insurance company is Traveler's. The accident happened in New York as well.

Comment: Can you edit and add country / state tags.

Comment: @Dheer Additional information added.